# GCD setting scheduling/priority between threads

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, avcapture, ios-multithreading

I am working on an app that captures frames from the camera and does blend over an image updated by another thread. My problem is that the image creating thread which is called every 500ms consumes peak computing power that influences the other thread.

Here some logs for clarification:

```
captureOutput(): used time:  0.027741014957428  , frame rate:  36.0477077545513
captureOutput(): used time:  0.0285720229148865  , frame rate:  34.9992719444091
captureOutput(): used time:  0.0310209989547729  , frame rate:  32.2362281581567
captureOutput(): used time:  0.0268059968948364  , frame rate:  37.3050852733863
captureOutput(): used time:  0.0263729691505432  , frame rate:  37.9176115624965
motionCallback(): starting drawing: 
captureOutput(): used time:  0.0376390218734741  , frame rate:  26.5681718127947
motionCallback(): elapesed time:  0.0835540294647217
captureOutput(): used time:  0.0581380128860474  , frame rate:  17.2004502795793
captureOutput(): used time:  0.0364410281181335  , frame rate:  27.4415967836645
captureOutput(): used time:  0.0278580188751221  , frame rate:  35.8963070734734
captureOutput(): used time:  0.0283130407333374  , frame rate:  35.3194137435949
captureOutput(): used time:  0.0271909832954407  , frame rate:  36.7768972947616
captureOutput(): used time:  0.0268760323524475  , frame rate:  37.2078730552999
```

As you can see captureOutput has a frame rate of over 30 fps. As soon as motionCallback creates the image the frame rate drops and then goes up again. Please note that motionCallback() is only called every 15th capture frame, so the average computing power should easily be enough.

captureOutput() is running on a queue created like this:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  self.m_captureSessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "CaptureSessionOutputQueue", attributes: DispatchQueueAttributes.serial)
}
```

Later on I setup AVCapture like this:

```
videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: self.m_captureSessionQueue)
```

motionCallback() is set up like this:

```
let interval = 0.4
if m_manager.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
  m_manager.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = true
  m_manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = interval
  // XArbitraryCorrectedZVertical
  m_manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.xArbitraryCorrectedZVertical , to: OperationQueue.main, withHandler: motionCallback)
  print("viewDidLoad(): CM initialized !")
}
```

and later:

```
func motionCallback(_ motion: CMDeviceMotion?, error: NSError?) -> Void {
  guard let mot = motion else {return}
  print("motionCallback(): starting drawing: ")

  let start = NSDate() // <<<<<<<<<< Start time
  self.m_instrview?.update(attitude: mot.attitude)
  self.m_overlayImage = CIImage(image: self.m_instrview!.generateImage()!)

  let end = NSDate()  // <<<<<<<<<<   end time
  let timeInterval: Double = end.timeIntervalSince(start as Date)
  print("motionCallback(): elapesed time: ", timeInterval)
}
```

and generateImage() like this:

```
func generateImage() -> UIImage {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main().scale )
  drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
  let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
  return image!
}
```

The idea is to create every time the CoreMotion system get me an update I will generate a new image.

My question is how can I average out the computation time of motionCallback() so that it does not consume peak cpu power that causes the frame rate to drop ? So I would accept it to run 10x longer but consume only a 1/10th of cpu during that time.

Any ideas how this could be controlled ?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Your motion callback is on the main queue, which includes the call to `generateImage` which seems to be the function that is CPU intensive. Note that if you dispatch this onto a background queue you must still perform UI updates on the main queue

Comment: Yes that's exactly my problem, the CPU intensive function MUST be called on the main thread. So, if I can't down-prioritize motionCallBack, what about up-prioritzing the capturing thread. How can I do that ?

Comment: Why do you say the cpu intensive function must be called on the main thread?  generateImage is cpu intensive but can run on a background thread. Once it is done dispatch the assignment of the CIImage on the main thread. Use a low priority thread for processing your core motion events

Comment: generateImage basically contains a call to UIView.drawHierarchy() which is the time consuming part. When I call UIView.drawHierarchy() outside the main thread I don't get any views rendered into the image. That's why I wrote MUST be called...

Comment: Then I suggest you use the time profiler instrument to see if you can identify a particular issue, otherwise share the code that isn't performing

Answer (score 1):

Create an async queue (using dispatch_queue_create) with a lower priority than the one that does your frame capturing. Run your motionCallback on this lower priority  queue.

You have your motionCapture method running on the main queue, which runs its tasks on the main thread. Don't do that.

This line is wrong:

```
m_manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(
  using: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.xArbitraryCorrectedZVertical , 
  to: OperationQueue.main, 
  withHandler: motionCallback)
```

Change the to: parameter.

You need to create a new serial queue that runs at a lower priority than the CaptureSessionOutputQueue you create, and pass that in the to: parameter above.

I'm just starting to learn Swift 3 so I don't have the syntax of the new code for creating dispatch queues yet.

Comment: what I already did is to put that code into     DispatchQueue.global(attributes: .qosBackground).async { ... }, but this lead to compete freeze of the GUI. Can it be that drawHierarchy must be called on main thread ?

Comment: So edit your question to include the details of your queue setup, as well as the relevant parts of the code that both queues are running.

Comment: Yes, a call that draws images into a context almost certainly must be called on the main thread.

Comment: A separate queue did not solve the problem. I get a crash saying that it must be called on the main thread. So separating into a different queue is not an option. Any further ideas ? What about increasing the priority of the capture queue ? How to do that in DGC/Swift 3 ?